# How to use GroupBy() and Min() with Entity Framework Core ASP .NET

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Let's say my database table *Agents* is the following,

```
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
| AgentCode  | AgentName            | WorkingArea        | Commission | PhoneNo         | Country |
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
| A007       | Ramasundar           | Bangalore          |       0.15 | 077-25814763    |         |
| A003       | Alex                 | London             |       0.13 | 075-12458969    |         |
| A008       | Alford               | New York           |       0.12 | 044-25874365    |         |
| A011       | Ravi Kumar           | Bangalore          |       0.15 | 077-45625874    |         |
| A010       | Santakumar           | Chennai            |       0.14 | 007-22388644    |         |
| A012       | Lucida               | San Jose           |       0.12 | 044-52981425    |         |
| A005       | Anderson             | Brisban            |       0.13 | 045-21447739    |         |
| A001       | Subbarao             | Bangalore          |       0.14 | 077-12346674    |         |
| A002       | Mukesh               | Mumbai             |       0.11 | 029-12358964    |         |
| A006       | McDen                | London             |       0.15 | 078-22255588    |         |
| A004       | Ivan                 | Torento            |       0.15 | 008-22544166    |         |
| A009       | Benjamin             | Hampshair          |       0.11 | 008-22536178    |         |
+------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+---------+
```

What I exactly need to query is as the following(in SQL for better understanding).

```
SELECT WorkingArea, MIN(Commission) 
FROM agents 
GROUP BY WorkingArea;
```

And its result is:-

```
WorkingArea                         MIN(Commission)
----------------------------------- ---------------
San Jose                                        .12
Torento                                         .15
London                                          .13
Hampshair                                       .11
New York                                        .12
Brisban                                         .13
Bangalore                                       .14
Chennai                                         .14
Mumbai                                          .11
```

**How can I do the same with .NET Entity Framework?**

I tried the following. But it gave me only the MIN(COMMISSION) row.

```
IEnumerable<Agent> AgentList = _db.Agents
                .GroupBy(fields => fields.WorkingArea)
                .Select(fields => new Agent
                {
                    Commission = fields.Min(fields => fields.Commission)
                });


// If my Model name is Agent its corresponding database table name will be Agent**s**.
```

**Update 1**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**1. How can I do the equivalent to the sql query above, with .NET Entity Framework?**

**2. What if I want add also the *PhoneNo* column to the result? like**

```
    SELECT WorkingArea, MIN(Commission), PhoneNo 
    FROM agents 
    GROUP BY WorkingArea;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another type (not `Agent`) for the result output. Either define a two-field class

```
class WorkingAreaCommission
{
    public string WorkingArea { get; set; }
    public double Commission { get; set; }
}
```

or use anonymous type:

```
var AgentList = _db.Agents
    .GroupBy(fields => fields.WorkingArea)
    .Select(fields => new
    {
        WorkingArea = fields.Key,
        Commission = fields.Min(fields => fields.Commission)
    });
```

**Update (to answer a question from comments)**

If you need result containing more than just key and minimal values, sort by the field you need minimal value from and extract all required fields from the first record:

```
var AgentList = _db.Agents
    .GroupBy(fields => fields.WorkingArea)
    .Select(fields => fields
        .OrderBy(x => x.Commission)
        .Select(x => new {
            WorkingArea = x.WorkingArea,
            PhoneNo = x.PhoneNo,
            Commission = x.Commission
        })
        .First()
    );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort Dmitry Egorov. I wanna know what does 'fields.Key' mean? What if I want to add also the "PhoneNo" field to the expected result.

Comment: `GroupBy` linq operation returns `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`, which means it transforms your initial collection into another collection. I that new collection each element is a group (also a collection, or `IEnumerable<TElement>`) of elements selected by the grouping condition. Additionally, each such group has a key (`fields.Key` in your case), which is a value defining this group, i.e. the value you return in `GroupBy`'s key selector function (it's `fields.WorkingArea` in your case).